# Twitter bootstrap icons and <input type="button>

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I've trying to put two icons for vote up/down but I'm not sure how exactly to do this. Current code havehasonly two `<input type="button">` now need to put icons on them. This is what I try so far:

```
<div class="btn-votes">
    <div class="like">
        <i class="icon-like"> 
            <input type="button" title="Up" class="up" onClick="addVote('.$row['image_id'].',\'1\')" '.$up.' />
        </i>
    </div>
    <div class="dislike">
        <i class="icon-dislike">
             <input type="button" title="Down" class="down" onClick="addVote('.$row['image_id'].',\'-1\')" '.$down.' />
        </i>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is the AJAX part.

```
function addVote(image_id,vote_rank) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "add_vote.php",
        data:'image_id='+image_id+'&vote_rank='+vote_rank,
        type: "POST",
    beforeSend: function(){
        $('#links-'+image_id+' .btn-votes').html("<img src='img/loaderIcon.gif' />");
    },
    success: function(vote_rank_status){
        var votes = parseInt($('#votes-'+image_id).val());
        var vote_rank_status;
        switch(vote_rank) {
            case "1":
            votes = votes+1;
            break;
            case "-1":
            votes = votes-1;
            break;
    }
       console.log(vote_rank_status);
    $('#votes-'+image_id).val(votes);
    $('#vote_rank_status-'+image_id).val(vote_rank_status);

        var up,down;

        if(vote_rank_status == 1) {
            up="disabled";
            down="enabled";
        }
        if(vote_rank_status == -1) {
            up="enabled";
            down="disabled";

        }    

        var vote_button_html = '<input type="button" title="Up" id="up" onClick="addVote('+image_id+',\'1\')" '+up+' /><div class="label-votes">'+votes+'</div><input type="button" title="Down" id="down"  onClick="addVote('+image_id+',\'-1\')" '+down+' />';    
            $('#links-'+image_id+' .btn-votes').html(vote_button_html);
        }


    });
    }
```

I'm not sure where is the problem but in web console I see the error

> ReferenceError: addVote is not defined

which I think mean that can't pass `onClick` event to the AJAX function. So how should those buttons be?

This is the current HTML which is working just fine

```
<div class="btn-votes">
    <input type="button" title="Up" class="up" onClick="addVote('.$row['image_id'].',\'1\')" '.$up.' />
    <input type="button" title="Down" class="down" onClick="addVote('.$row['image_id'].',\'-1\')" '.$down.' />  
</div>
```

UPDATE: Current code

```
<div class="btn-votes">
    <div class="like">
         <button title="Up" class="up" onClick="addVote('.$row['image_id'].',\'1\')" '.$up.' />
               <i class="icon-like"> </i>
         </button>
    </div>
    <div class="dislike">                                  
          <button title="Down" class="down" onClick="addVote('.$row['image_id'].',\'-1\')" '.$down.' />
               <i class="icon-dislike"></i>
          </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: To put an icon in to a button, use the `button` element, not `input type="button"`. Secondly, there is no `addVote()` function defined in your code, hence the error.

Comment: Thank's for the comment. I've added current code which is working and also doesn't have `addVote` in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind onclick event on button, however, you should bind the function by jquery and not by onclick, as the onclick will trigger outside of your function scope :

```
var vote_button_html = '<div class="like">' +
                           '<i class="icon-like">' +
                               '<input type="button" title="Up" id="up" '+up+' />' +
                            '</i>' + 
                       '</div>' +
                       '<div class="label-votes">'+votes+'</div>' +
                       '<div class="dislike">' +
                           '<i class="icon-dislike">' +
                               '<input type="button" title="Down" id="down" '+down+' />' +
                           '</i>' + 
                       '</div>';    

var vote_button = $(vote_button_html);

vote_button.find("#up").on("click", function(){
    addVote(image_id,1);
});
vote_button.find("#down").on("click", function(){
    addVote(image_id,-1);
});

$('#links-'+image_id+' .btn-votes ').empty().append(vote_button);
```

Note that if you have multiple vote button on your page, you **MUST** change the id up and down from id to class as id **MUST BE UNIQUE**

Comment: I suppose this is for the `.js` file where is the ajax function? I have only on one place those buttons.

Comment: Yes, in place of `var vote_button_html = '<div class="like"><i class="icon-like"><input type="button" title="Up" id="up" onClick="addVote(' + image_id + ',\'1\')" ' + up + ' /></i></div><div class="label-votes">' + votes + '</div><div class="dislike"><i class="icon-dislike"><input type="button" title="Down" id="down"  onClick="addVote(' + image_id + ',\'-1\')" ' + down + ' /></i></div>';    
        $('#links-' + image_id + ' .btn-votes ').html(vote_button_html);`

Comment: Same error in console. Also I see you put `onClick` on the `up` button but there is no `onClick` on down button. Why is this?

Comment: If you still have the error, where is your addVote function ?

Comment: Yes, is still there this error. I've added full original `vote.js` file in the question.

Comment: I've just tested, if you just replace the var vote_button_html and the next line by my code, it works

Comment: With `<button>` or with `<input>`? I just tested again with your code and `<input type...` and still got `ReferenceError: addVote is not defined`

Comment: If the code is placed inside the addVote closure (eq:function), then it can be accessed. have you an existing html with the up/down button with the onClick attribute ?

Comment: Current(working) code is the last portion of source under the `UPDATE` in my question. This is the current and working HTML code along with the `ajax` part which is also in the my question. On the original code on the buttons are used images defined in `CSS` but I want to change them whit this from bootstrap/Font Awesome ..

Comment: Is it possible because they are in `div btn-votes` and then each button is also in separated div. I mean `<div class="dislike">` and `<div class="like">`? edit: possible for this error i mean.

Comment: One last thing. This `'<div class="label-votes">'+votes+'</div>' +` how can I show also when is ready like buttons here: `vote_button.find("#down").on("click", function(){...`

Answer (score 0):

First, the addVote() function does not exist, so wrap your ajax call in it.

```
function addVote(image_id, vote_rank) {
    $.ajax({
    url: "add_vote.php",
    data:'image_id='+image_id+'&vote_rank='+vote_rank,
    type: "POST",        
    beforeSend: function(){
        $('#links-'+image_id+' .btn-votes').html("<img src='loaderIcon.gif' />");
    },

    success: function(vote_rank_status){
         console.log(vote_rank_status);
    var votes = parseInt($('#votes-'+image_id).val());
    var vote_rank_status;
    switch(vote_rank) {
        case "1":
        votes = votes+1;
        break;
        case "-1":
        votes = votes-1;
        break;

    }
    $('#votes-'+image_id).val(votes);
    $('#vote_rank_status-'+image_id).val(vote_rank_status);

    var up,down;

    if(vote_rank_status == 1) {
        up="disabled";
        down="enabled";
    }
    if(vote_rank_status == -1) {
        up="enabled";
        down="disabled";
    }   
    var vote_button_html = '<div class="like"><i class="icon-like"><input type="button" title="Up" id="up" onClick="addVote('+image_id+',\'1\')" '+up+' /></i></div><div class="label-votes">'+votes+'</div><div class="dislike"><i class="icon-dislike"><input type="button" title="Down" id="down"  onClick="addVote('+image_id+',\'-1\')" '+down+' /></i></div>';    
    $('#links-'+image_id+' .btn-votes ').html(vote_button_html);
    }
    });
}
```

Then, do not use `<input type="button" />`, but `<button></button>`, and put the icon inside.

```
<button class="btn" onClick="addVote(id, rank)">
    <i class="fa fa-send"></i>
</button>
```

If you are already using jquery, you might wanna drop the onclick and do something like:

```
$('body').on('click', '.up, .down', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    addVote($(this).attr('data-id'), $(this).attr('data-rank'));
    return false;
});
```

And echo the php in `data` attributes of course.

Comment: Thank's. I've updated my question with how I've made them after your answer. But still same. I have `function addVote(image_id, vote_rank) {...` I just didn't copy it for the question. My mistake.

Comment: where is your `addVote()` function located ? You should declare it outside of any scope.

Comment: I've added full original `vote.js` file in the question. I include `vote.js` in the file where are buttons.

Comment: I'm really new in js/ajax at all and don't know how to do this is this suppose to be in the head of the page? `$('body').on('click', '.up, .down', function(e){...`

Comment: You need to put that in your `$(document).ready()` function. `addVote()` should be outside of that or next to the `.on()` event listener. You can also drop the addVote function and put you ajax call in the listener.